# Calling module methods with whenever cron jobs, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module, model, cron, whenever

I am trying to call a module that I have in /lib folder

```
module Reports  
  module MyMod
    def test 
    ....Test methods...
    end
 end
end
```

In Rails Console, this is called with

```
 include Reports::MyMod; test
```

In /config.schedule.rb I tried

```
every 1.minute do
   runner 'Reports::MyMod.test'
   runner 'Reports.MyMod.test'
   runner 'include Reports::MyMod; conc'

end
```

None of which works, how do I call this method? Also how do I call this method from a model?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you just want to use modules as a namespace for the method. In such cases you can create a class method:

```
module Reports  
  module MyMod
    class << self 
      def test 
        ....Test methods...
      end

      #more methods
   end
 end
end
```

And then you can call it:

```
Reports::MyMod.test
```

The reason you couldn't do it this way before is because it was declared as an instance method and modules can't be instantiated. For that you'll need to include it into a class.

Make sure the file is autoloaded, otherwise you'll need to explicitly require it first.

Comment: can you explain autoloaded, it is not autoloaded by itself?

Comment: I'm just saying you should make sure the file path is in the autoloade path and the directory follows the Rails convention.